# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator " using value $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When i go in the page, in console appear: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'height' in undefined,
and before the value of 0 (from the line console.log(i); )
I want to call ajax on "i" after I clicked on the element.
I don't understand why apper Uncaught TypeError, and why it enter in loadSingleIns(i) without any click.

The script is:

```
..... success: function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response));
                var instructor=JSON.parse(response);
                var el="";
        for(var i=0;i<instructor.length;i++){
             $(document).on ("click", ".insegnanti#i"+[i+1], loadSingleIns(i));
                  ....
```

And the function called is:

```
function loadSingleIns(i){

        console.log(i);
$(this).animate({
opacity: 0.25,
left: "+=50",
height: "toggle"
}, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
  });
//here i want to call ajax for the element i

}
```

I know there are some questions like this, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: It runs the function without a click because of the parens `()` after the `loadSingleIns` function. That's how a function is called. To pass a reference remove the parens

Comment: console.log(this) and you'll see that it doesnt point where you think it does

Comment: `".insegnanti#i"+[i+1]` makes me reel a little bit. I'm assuming that those elements are already on the page? It would make more sense to have a specific class `.insegnanti` that you can click on (eliminating the loop), and have the element id in a data attribute or something.

Comment: Event handler in a loop is scary!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to pass the handler reference in third parameter of on where you are call the function `loadSingleIns`

```
$(document).on ("click", ".insegnanti#i"+[i+1], loadSingleIns);
```

To get the i from id you can use following code.

```
function loadSingleIns(){
    i = this.id.replace('i','');
}
```

As a additional note you may thing about the selector,  `".insegnanti#i"+[i+1]` as the ids are supposed to be unique you can remove the class selector from the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to pass params in `loadSingleIns` function, element reference and Event automatic pass in function..

```
$(document).on ("click", ".insegnanti#i"+[i+1], loadSingleIns);
```

or if you really want to pass params then call function inside callback function

```
$(document).on ("click", ".insegnanti#i"+[i+1], function(Event){
      loadSingleIns(Event, this);
});
// function with 2 params
function loadSingleIns(e, refe){
  console.log(e, refe)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment this code

```
for(var i=0;i<instructor.length;i++){
  $(document).on ("click", ".insegnanti#i"+[i+1], loadSingleIns(i));
```

aside from the `loadSingleIns(i)` issue - doesn't look right at all. That's not really how you should be using classes. Perhaps you meant to use id attributes instead...

Assuming all those elements are on the page already you can get rid of the loop altogether, bundle those elements using the same class, and have the id of the element in a separate attribute:

HTML

```
<div class="insegnant" data-id="1">Element 1</div>
<div class="insegnant" data-id="2">Element 2</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.insegnanti', loadSingleIns);

function loadSingleIns() {

  var id = $(this).data('id');

  $(this).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {

    // when the animation has completed run the ajax
    // this example adds the id on to the end of the URL
    // you can move this function outside of the animation if you want
    // I thought it would be better here
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://demo.com/id=' + id
      ...
      success: function (data) {
        // do something with data
      }
    });

  });
}
```